# Unit Testing with Mocha Jade/Javascript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js, pug

I have a jade file and corresponding javascript file. the Div elements are defined in jade file and i am using getElementById to access those element in javascript file dynamically. How should i write test cases ? In Mocha I am getting error like " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

Comment: How to include that jade structure inside the test file?

Comment: You will probably need to first compile that Pug template code to HTML, and then run the tests with that HTML code. But where are the tests run? Are they linked from that jade template, or are they run independently in a node environment, or from another different page?

Comment: They are running independently in a node nvironment. But I am calling my javascript function in a separate test file after giving an export statement for those functions. I am using mocha.

Comment: In any case, I've not yet heard of tests accessing raw Jade/Pug files, I think you need to first compile that Pug template down to HTML, and then you should be able to access its elements from the test suite

Comment: How can this be done?